# Excel VBA User Defined Function That Reads and Returns Data from a Database Doesn't Always Work. Why?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, database, ado

I have written a user defined function (udf) to run a select statement in access, and return the recordset as an array to an Excel spreadsheet. The function takes as its arguments two strings: a connection string for the Access database (e.g. "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"), and a SQL string.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't work I get a #VALUE! error in my spreadsheet. I don't know what causes it to fail when it's unsuccessful. Please help me to solve this issue.

Here is my code:

```
Function udfREADDB(connection As String, sql As String) As Variant
    
    Dim db As ADODB.connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, varArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer ' rows & cols
    
    Set db = New ADODB.connection
    With db
        .ConnectionString = connection
        .ConnectionTimeout = 10
        .Open
    End With
    
     ' Query database
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open sql, db
    
    ReDim varArray(0 To rs.RecordCount, 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1)
    
    ' Read headings to array
    For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        varArray(0, j) = rs.Fields(j).Name
    Next j
    
    ' Read data to array
    For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            varArray(i, j) = rs.Fields(j)
        Next j
        
        rs.MoveNext
    Next i
        
    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    udfREADDB = varArray
    
End Function
```

I have tried putting a breakpoint into the code. Then, when I call the udf from a cell in the spreadsheet, the code pauses as expected. I then go through each element of the code (each variable) and nothing indicates an error. I can even use the immediate pane to return elements of my array, varArray(), and it's fine. The same goes for UBound(varArray, 1) or UBound(varArray, 2).

I wondered if the error was caused by too long a path name, but wouldn't this show up as an error in VBA as well as the spreadsheet?

I created a test database containing a table with 100 rows and five fields (an integer, a double, a string, a Boolean and a datetime). The spreadsheet is populated with the data as expected: I use the formula "{=udfREADDB(A1,A2)}" with Shift+Ctrl+Enter in the cells A11:E101.

When I pasted my test database in a location with a long path I did manage to recreate the error. However, when I took a copy of a database that is stored in a location with a long path, and pasted it in C:\, my udf still returned a #VALUE! error, as it did to begin with.

I have used a Sub() in VBA to call my function and I use Debug.Print to see the size of the array that is created, but this doesn't help because no error is generated.

I'm running out of ideas as to how to troubleshoot this issue :(

Comment: If you put break point on the last line `End Function`, does it exit before it hits the break point and return #`VALUE!`?

Comment: You don't have to use loop. You can get the recordset as an array with a = rs.getrows. However, the array has been transpoed.

Comment: @Dy.Lee thanks for the tip about rs.getrows!

Comment: When you say sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, is the SQL always the same? My suspicion is that this is a data issue. Under certain circumstances the SQL returns data that cannot be displayed in the sheet. I would try running a query that doesn't work inside Access itself and look at the values returned.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld when I put the breakpoint at that location I can see that the cell contains the value '0' until I hit F5 in the VBA, at which point it changes to #VALUE!.

Comment: With the code stopped at that point, compare the contents and dimensions of varArray between values that produce a result and values that produce an error

Comment: @JonathanWillcock thanks for your suggestion. I've been using different SQL strings and different Access databases. I've been testing the SQL I use in the function by copying it and pasting it into Access, and then running it in Access. The SQL always works in Access, and returns a set of records. When I deliberately pass some incorrect SQL to the function, e.g. "SELECT * FROMTable1" (missing space), the function fails at the ````rs.open sql, db```` line.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks for this. I've used the immediate window to find the size of the array created by the code and it matches the size of the record set created in Access in all cases that I've tested, whether a #VALUE! is returned in the spreadsheet or not. The same goes for the contents of the array. The test database that I mention in the original post no-longer returns a #VALUE! error from the longer file path, so I can't do exactly as you say. The problem seems to lie with different Access databases, where some databases are fine and others are not??

Comment: I'm not so much concerned with the database as it appears in access as with the data in varArray. Your test results seem to imply a data issue as pointed out by Jonathan.

Comment: I've solved it with thanks for everyone's help. It was a data issue. Some of the tables I was querying had ````Null```` values in them, which VBA can handle, but which Excel cannot. The solution is to use ````If IsNull(rs.Fields(j)) Then …```` when the array is being populated to catch them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears in the spreadsheet because it cannot handle Nulls. The solution, then, is to catch the Nulls and replace them with something else; either vbNullString, 0, or "NULL". My preference is vbNullString. This is achieved by using the IsNull() function. VBA can handle Nulls, but Excel can't.

```
Function udfREADDB(connection As String, sql As String) As Variant
    
    Dim db As ADODB.connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, varArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer ' rows & cols
    
    Set db = New ADODB.connection
    With db
        .ConnectionString = connection
        .ConnectionTimeout = 10
        .Open
    End With
    
     ' Query database
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open sql, db
    
    ReDim varArray(0 To rs.RecordCount, 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1)
    
    ' Read headings to array
    For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        varArray(0, j) = rs.Fields(j).Name
    Next j
    
    ' Read data to array
    For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            If IsNull(rs.Fields(j)) Then
                varArray(i, j) = vbNullString
            Else
                varArray(i, j) = rs.Fields(j)
            End If
        Next j
        
        rs.MoveNext
    Next i
        
    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    udfREADDB = varArray
    
End Function
```